# Tumour heterogeneity in scRNA-seq - cell-to-cell correlation

Tags: correlation

I'm trying to derive a measure of Tumours heterogeneity in scRNA-seq data. For a given individual's scRNA-seq gene expression matrix, I could like to calculate the Pearson correlations with and between clusters (compare the average cell-to-cell correlation within clusters and the average cell-to-cell correlation between clusters).

The idea is that if an individual had substantial transcriptional heterogeneity, the intercluster correlation would be negative and within-cluster correlation would be positive. If the individual's Tumours had a uniform transcriptional state, they would have a near-zero intercluster correlation. I am using the `cor()` function from the R 'stats' package and using the log-normalized gene expression matrix as input:

```
c2.dat <- data.frame(c2@assays$RNA@data) #gene expression matrix for a subject's cells in "cluster 2"
c2.cor <- cor(c2.dat, method = "pearson") #correlation analysis on log-normalized gene expression matrix
```

I am stuck though once I have a correlation matrix. How do I calculate the average cell-to-cell correlation within this cluster?

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you considered asking on https://www.biostars.org/ ? It's similar to stack overflow but dedicated to bioinformatics. You may have more chances of getting an answer. I never worked on single cell, so I have no idea!

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Thank you!